# Intellij interpreter is not finding entries in pom-declared jar although its browser successfully resolves

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

The following is an entry from the `spark-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/core` `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.razorvine</groupId>
  <artifactId>pyrolite</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>net.razorvine</groupId>
      <artifactId>serpent</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Note that ( a) this builds fine on the command line and (b) I made an update to the lastest version (4.9 -> 4.12)

The issue is the interpreter for some reason is not finding these entries : as shown in red below right.  The browser is having no issue to find them (below left):

[image]

So .. any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: sounds familiar. try this: in the Maven Projects tool window, click the Reimport All Maven Projects tool button.

Comment: @kem Thx but that's the first thing one tries..  I had already done that in this case  many times.